# Strategy TradingView Average Price - strategy.position_avg_price

Tags: pine-script

I use the condition [strategy.position_avg_price] to design possible outputs. There is a problem, when you run a strategy alert in TradingView, it runs late. How to implement condition [strategy.position_avg_price] in a study?

```
order_size =input(50, title="Order Size")

//average price

var quantity_sum = 0.0
var value_sum = 0.0

if () <- your entry condition
    quantity_sum := quantity_sum + (order_size/close)
    value_sum := value_sum + order_size

avg_price = value_sum/quantity_sum

if() <- your condition to close
    quantity_sum := quantity_sum * 0
    value_sum := value_sum * 0

plot(quantity_sum > 0 ? avg_price : na, color = color.lime, linewidth = 4)
```

So I do the calculation of entries and a single closing. Does anyone have an idea to cut down on partial execution?

Comment: "...it runs late" - could you explain this? Maybe we will can find the decision.